# Change image name if already exist then upload to database and directory

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Below is my code which works fine but how can I add "_copy" in image name when image name already exist and then upload it to "artworks" directory and insert updated name in "Artworks" table

```
$targeta = "artworks/";
    $targeta = $targeta . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    $pic=($_FILES['image']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $targeta)){
       echo "Image uploaded";
    }
    else {
       echo "Image name already exist";
    }
    $results = $db->query("INSERT INTO Artworks (`Image`) VALUES ('$pic');");
    if($results){
    echo "New row inserted";
    }
```

Comment: Check with `file_exists` and `!is_dir` before you add a prrfix to the file name.

Comment: _NEVER_ trust `$_FILES['image']['name']` in any way. Store it in the database, but use the _id_ returned from the database as the actual key on the file system (and with a random key added in if you're going to be storing them in a web accessible location).

Comment: You're not escaping the value of `$pic` when inserting it into the database either, so you're vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (i.e. don't trust `name` for uploaded files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `file_exists($targeta)` and rename and move it to destination.

```
$target_path = "artworks/";
$targeta = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
$pic=($_FILES['image']['name']);

if(file_exists($targeta)) {
    $lastdot = strrpos($_FILES['image']['name'], '.');
    $basefilename = substr($_FILES['image']['name'], 0, $lastdot);
    $extension = substr($_FILES['image']['name'], $lastdot);
    $pic = $basefilename . '_copy' . $extension;
    $targeta = $target_path . $pic;
    echo "Image name already exist. Renaming to: " . $pic;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $targeta)){
   echo "Image uploaded";
}
else {
   echo "Cannot move file to destination";
}
$results = $db->query("INSERT INTO Artworks (`Image`) VALUES ('$pic');");
if($results){
echo "New row inserted";
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me but didn't worked, showing syntax error, unexpected '$extension' (T_VARIABLE) on line 350(where $extension variable is declared) @Memborg

Comment: its because Memborg forgot `;`  after `$basefilename = substr($_FILES['image']['name'], 0, $lastdot)` I have updated it. try now @ShujaatShaikh

Comment: yes @B. Desai absolutely right, that was the issue..solved ! Thanks